# Question regarding compactness when intermediate value theorem (kind of) holds

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a space s.t every continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ has the following property: if $a<c<b$ and $f(x)=a$, $f(y)=b$ then there exists $z\in X$ s.t. $f(z)=c$.
Prove that $X$ is compact.

This is a question that was in a practice exam of last year.

My attempt (if you can call it that):
I only know what the result should be. So you probably take a given cover and prove that it is finite but I don't see the connection between a continuous function with this property and a cover being finite.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I only know what the result should be. So you probably take a given cover and prove that it is finite but I don't see the connection between a continuous function with this property and a cover being finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not true. For example take $X=\mathbb{R}$. Then this is the intermediate value theorem (a bit weaker variant), but $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

What you probably wanted to say is "Prove that $X$ is connected" instead. Indeed, if $X$ is disconnected, then it can be written as $X=U\cup V$ where $U$, $V$ are open, disjoint and nonempty. Then the following function:

$$f:X\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }x\in U \\
1&\text{if }x\in V
\end{cases}$$

is continuous and a counterexample.

Note that the converse is also true: if $X$ is connected then it does satisfy this variant of intermediate value theorem. This is because continuous functions map connected subsets to connected subsets, and connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals.

In other words the intermediate value theorem can be seen as "mapping connected subsets to connected subsets".

Comment: That makes more sense indeed. I probably copied it wrong. Thanks!